# Schema design: Use of association (aka: bridge/junction) table vs foreign key constraint with composite index containing a non-key field

Tags: sql-server-2008, index, foreign-key, database-design

This is an inventory database for IT assets. The models used are trimmed in order to focus on the problem at hand. Using SQL Server 2008. Thanks for taking the time to read and for any input you can provide.

My design includes a `Device` table which holds the various devices that can be entered into inventory. Each device has a boolean flag, `CanNetwork` which states whether a device has network capability, e.g., for most computers `CanNetwork = true`, for hard drives `CanNetwork = false`; some printers will be true, and others will be false. You get the idea.

The `CanNetwork` field determines if network-related information is relevant when an inventory record is created.

### Design 1

My first design uses an index on `Device.DeviceID` and `Device.CanNetwork` to use in a foreign key constraint with the `Asset` table.

[image: Schema #1: Foreign key constraint with index]

The `NetworkStatus` table looks like this in this setup:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NetworkStatusID | NetworkStatus  | NetworkStatusDescription          |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1               | Connected      | Device connected to network.      |
| 2               | Not Connected  | Device not connected to network.  |
| 3               | Do Not Connect | Do not connect device to network. |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I put check constraints on the `Asset` table as follows to ensure a network status and network information can only be provided if the device is capable of connecting to a network.

```
-- Asset table check constraint: CK_CanNetwork
-- If can't network, then network fields are null
CanNetwork = 0
AND NetworkStatusID IS NULL
AND Hostname IS NULL
AND IPAddress IS NULL
AND MACAddress IS NULL
OR CanNetwork = 1

-- Asset table check constraint: CK_NetworkStatus
-- If network status is "Connected", then must provide
-- a hostname or ip address
NetworkStatusID = 1 AND Hostname IS NOT NULL
OR NetworkStatusID = 1 AND IPAddress IS NOT NULL
OR NetworkStatusID <> 1
```

The issue I have with this design is I'm not sure if the relationship with `Asset` and  `Device.DeviceID`/`Device.CanNetwork` is a good or bad design decision. Is propagating a non-key field like `CanNetwork` to other tables a bad design? I don't have enough experience with database design to make an informed decision.

---

### Design 2

In this design I thought I would use a bridge/association/junction table to decide which network statuses are valid for a device. It looks like this:

[image]

The `NetworkStatus` table looks like this in this setup (Notice the addition of record with id #4, and the `ForCanNetwork` field which specifies that this status is for use with devices that can can connect to a network):

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NetworkStatusID | NetworkStatus  | NetworkStatusDescription          | ForCanNetwork |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1               | Connected      | Device connected to network.      | True  (1)     |
| 2               | Not Connected  | Device not connected to network.  | True  (1)     |
| 3               | Do Not Connect | Do not connect device to network. | True  (1)     |
| 4               | Incapable      | Cannot connect to networks.       | False (0)     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Due to this design's granularity, I could theoretically allow any mix of statuses for devices with this design, but I wanted to control it so I wrote some triggers to only insert the correct mix of statuses depending on whether the device is network capable. Triggers as follows:

```
-- NetworkStatus table on INSERT trigger
-- Adds a record for each device that
-- matches the capability of the network status
INSERT INTO DeviceNetworkStatus
SELECT i.NetworkStatusID, dev.DeviceID
FROM Device dev
CROSS JOIN
inserted i
WHERE dev.CanNetwork = i.ForCanNetwork

-- Device table on INSERT trigger
-- Adds a record for each network status that
-- matches the capability of the new device
INSERT INTO DeviceNetworkStatus
SELECT ns.NetworkStatusID, i.DeviceID
FROM NetworkStatus ns
CROSS JOIN
inserted i
WHERE ns.ForCanNetwork = i.CanNetwork
```

I used the following CHECK constraint on the `Asset` table:

```
-- Asset table check constraint: CK_NetworkStatus
-- If network status is "Connected', then must provide
-- a hostname or ip address
-- If network status is "Incapable", then network fields
-- must be null
NetworkStatusID = 1 AND Hostname IS NOT NULL
OR NetworkStatusID = 1 AND IPAddress IS NOT NULL
OR NetworkStatusID = 4 AND Hostname IS NULL
AND IPAddress IS NULL AND MACAddress IS NULL
OR NetworkStatusID <> 1 AND NetworkStatusID <> 4
```

This design eliminates the need to propagate `CanNetwork` across the tables. The issue I see with this design is that every device that has network capability will have records in `DeviceNetworkStatus` paired with `NetworkStatus` ids 1, 2 and 3, while devices that can't connect to a network will be paired only with `NetworkStatus` id 4. It seems like a lot of extra records that all mean the same thing: devices that can be networked can only use statuses 1, 2 and 3, and devices that can't network only use 4. This design seems to be more "relationally correct", but also smells a bit.

### Update

The following update proposes variations on Design 1. I come across situations like this often, where there are many ways to achieve the same end result. I never know how to tell if there are hidden problems with the designs, and I can't judge when to normalize or denormalize. Is one of these designs preferred over the other and why?

### Design 1.1

[image: Schema #1.1: NetworkAsset subtype]

```
-- NetworkAsset table check constraint: CK_CanNetwork
CanNetwork = 1

-- NetworkAsset table check constraint: CK_NetworkStatus
-- If network status is "Connected", then must provide
-- a hostname or ip address
NetworkStatusID = 1 AND Hostname IS NOT NULL
OR NetworkStatusID = 1 AND IPAddress IS NOT NULL
OR NetworkStatusID <> 1
```

### Design 1.2

[image: Schema #1.2: NetworkAsset and NetworkDevice subtype]

For the record, this design seems a bit absurd even to me, but this is my thought process.
In this one, the presence of a `DeviceID` in the `NetworkDevice` table is equivalent to saying `CanNetwork` = true in Design 1. The `NetworkAsset.NetworkDeviceID` has a foreign key constraint and is used to ensure only networkable devices are entered. Can do this using a CHECK constraint (see below), and by making `NetworkDeviceID` a computed column that is equal to `DeviceID`.

```
-- NetworkAsset table check constraint: CK_IsNetworkDevice
NetworkDeviceID = DeviceID
```

Comment: Design 1 is clean, lean, and correct. It can ensure 100% integrity of your data. We use such approaches in our system all the time, and they never fail. Design 2 cannot be implemented without triggers, and as such it is not completely reliable - triggers are not fully reliable.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I feel better knowing I'm on the right track with design 1. Do you know if there is any benefit to making a subtype table `NetworkAsset`?

Comment: Regarding your subtype table NetworkAsset, can you post your approach. The Devil is in the details, and I do not have enough information to answer your question yet ;)

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov I added Design 1.1 and 1.2 to give you an idea of what I'm thinking. I'm interested to hear your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: So far I cannot think of any situation when 1.2 would have any advantage at all. So, 1.1 is preferable, because it does what we want and it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I have a surprise for you: you don't need `CanNetwork` at all!

You have two sets of devices: all devices and devices that can be attached to the network.  Only the latter have a network status, and that status can be only one of two values: connected and not connected.  (There may be administrative values, too, such as what network it's allowed to attach to, or its netmask or something.  Those attributes also do not apply to non-networked devices.)

The presence of a device in the NetworkedDevices table indicates that it can be attached to the network.  Absence from that table means it cannot; that is what's known as the *Closed World Assumption*.

In general, the presence of a boolean valued column that indicates whether or not the thing has a relationship to another table is hint that you need two tables instead of a flag.

HTH.

Comment: I agree with you that in most cases it is not necessary. The reason I include it is so devices can declare whether they are capable of connecting to a network, for example a workstation can connect, some printer models (but not all) can connect, and (most, if not all) monitors cannot connect. I could then use the attribute to disallow users from entering network information for a device such as a monitor, that inherently does not have network capability. Please let me know if this sounds reasonable.